# Geometric interpretation of the second covariant derivative

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm having some doubts about the geometric representation of the second covariant derivative.

I know that $\triangledown^{}_a(\triangledown^{}_bv)=(\triangledown^{}_a\triangledown^{}_b)v+\triangledown^{}_{\triangledown^{}_ab}v$

So the Riemann tensor can be defined in two ways :

$R(a,b)v=\triangledown^{}_{a}(\triangledown^{}_{b}v)-\triangledown^{}_{b}(\triangledown^{}_{a}v)-\triangledown^{}_{[a,b]}v\quad$
or
$\quad R(a,b)v=(\triangledown^{}_{a}\triangledown^{}_{b})v-(\triangledown^{}_{b}\triangledown^{}_{a})v$

So far so good (correct me if I'm wrong).

But the problem arises when I read that the Riemann tensor represents the difference between a parallel transported vector along two parts of a closed path.

Because if $\triangledown^{}_{b}v$ is the parallel transported vector along b, then it stands to reason that $\triangledown^{}_{a}(\triangledown^{}_{b}v)$ is the transported vector along b and then a. But there would be a correction term, so the representation would be inexact.

And conversely, if $(\triangledown^{}_{a}\triangledown^{}_{b})v$ is the transported vector along the path b and then a, the representation would be correct, but I don't understand why...

So, which is correct, A or B ?

[image: Picture]

Edit : would the difference be linked with the torsion ? Are $\triangledown^{}_{a}(\triangledown^{}_{b}v)$ and $(\triangledown^{}_{a}\triangledown^{}_{b})v$ equal if the connection is torsion free ?

PS : why is the image not integrated in the post ? too large ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are mixing up (abstract) index notion with an index-free notation. If you take $\xi$, $\eta$ and $v$ to be vector fields, then $(\nabla_\xi\nabla_\eta)v$ does not make sense, since you can apply a covariant derivative only to a vector field and not to the operator $\nabla_\eta$. The equation you are looking for is that if you extend the covariant derivative to an operation on tensor fields, then given $v$, you can form the $\binom11$-tensor field $\nabla v$ defined by $\eta\mapsto \nabla_\eta v$. Applying the covariant derivative to that, one obtains a $\binom12$-tensor field which is usually denoted by $\nabla^2v$. This is indeed given by $(\nabla^2v)(\xi,\eta)=\nabla_\xi\nabla_\eta v-\nabla_{\nabla_\xi\eta}v$. Torsion-freness of the connection then implies that $\nabla_\xi\eta-\nabla_\eta\xi=[\xi,\eta]$ and using this, you see that the curvature is given by 
$$
R(\xi,\eta)(v)=(\nabla^2v)(\xi,\eta)-(\nabla^2v)(\eta,\xi)=\nabla_\xi\nabla_\eta v-\nabla_\eta\nabla_\xi v-\nabla_{[\xi,\eta]}v. 
$$
Your confusion probably comes from the fact that in (abstract) index notation, one would use $\nabla_av^b$ as a symbol for the $\binom11$-tensor field $\nabla v$. But here $a$ and $b$ are not vector fields but (abstract) indices (and you cannot leave out the "$b$", otherwise $v$ would be a function rather than a vector field). Correspondingly, $\nabla^2v$ will be denoted by $\nabla_a\nabla_bv^c$ (and again $a,b,c$ are indices and not vector fields). In this notation the definition of curvature via $\nabla^2v$ as above then indeed reads as $R_{ab}{}^c{}_dv^d=\nabla_a\nabla_bv^c-\nabla_b\nabla_av^c$.

Comment: Ok thanks, it clears some things right up that I had wrong, but I'm still confused about the geometric interpretation. I know I may give too much importance to it, but I need the visualization (for better or worse).
I'll work on all of this and get back.

Comment: There is not much geometry in all that. If you take directional derivative with the direction depending on the point, too, then a directional derivative of the result does not only depend on the second derivative of the initial object but also on how the direction changes in the point in question. (Just compute a derivative of $Df(x)(v(x))$ in the setting of classical analysis.)

Answer (score 2):

After putting all this aside for a while, here's a proposition for a visual answer to my question. Please tell me if something doesn't look right ^^
(note : the vectors are of course random, it's a schematic representation)

Here are the second covariant derivatives and the (contracted) Riemann tensor in the simplest case where $\triangledown^{}_{b}a=\triangledown^{}_{a}b=0$ and $\triangledown^{}_{[a,b]}=\triangledown^{}_{\triangledown^{}_{b}a}-\triangledown^{}_{\triangledown^{}_{a}b}=0$ :

[image: The (contracted) Riemann tensor]

Now in the general case (still torsion-free) with $\triangledown^{}_{[a,b]}v\neq 0$ :

[image: Most general case torsion free]

where (it's easier to represent it separately) :

[image: Rieman tensor general case]

"Not much geometry in all that" ? On the contrary, I think.